# How to return max value and associated index in Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to supply a tuple with the highest value from a column (yield) and the associated index value in the form `(index, value)`

I came up with:

```
t= (df['yield'].idxmax(),df['yield'].max())
```

But I'm wondering is there a nicer way to get these values (in a tuple)?

Comment: apart from defining your Series outside `s = df['yield']` (which would add a line of code and be less efficient memory-wise), I can't find a more elegant and readable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way. It is not a one-liner, but it avoids the need to effectively calculate the maximum twice.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'yield': [0, 1, 3, 5, 1, 9, 5]})

s = df.loc[df['yield'] == df['yield'].max(), 'yield']

res = next(zip(s.index, s))

print(res)

# (5, 9)
```

Alternatively:

```
s = df.loc[df['yield'].argmax()]

res = (s.name, s.iloc[0])
```